# Clase active con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de agregar una clase `active` a un elemento, pero necesito que la clase se agregue solo cuando le den click a un elemento de los 3, y si le doy a otro elemento se remueva y se agregue al elemento que le di click.

IMPORTANTE: Si le doy click a un elemento se agrega la clase, y si le vuelvo a dar click a ese elemento se tiene que remover esa clase y asi sucesivamente.

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-top-icons");
var icons = header[0].getElementsByClassName("content-icons");
for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-top-icons">
  <li>
    <a class="content-icons">primer icono</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="content-icons">segundo icono</a>
    </li>
   <li>
     <a class="content-icons">tercer icono</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien querrías algo así:

1. Si el elemento pulsado contiene la clase `active` se la quitamos
2. Si no la tiene primero quitamos la clase `active` a todos los elementos y luego se la añadimos a la pulsada.

```js
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-top-icons");
var icons = header[0].getElementsByClassName("content-icons");

for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  if(this.classList.contains("active")){
    this.classList.remove("active");
  }
  else{
  //Borramos de todos los elementos la clase "active"
   for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
     icons[i].classList.remove("active");
   }
   //Se la añadimos al elemento pulsado
    this.classList.add("active");    
  }  
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-top-icons">
  <li>
    <a class="content-icons">primer icono</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a class="content-icons">segundo icono</a>
    </li>
   <li>
     <a class="content-icons">tercer icono</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ha servido, justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con `jQuery` de una forma más rápida y fácil,  [Demo](https://codepen.io/dmsanchez86/pen/xBVbGz)

```js
$(".content-icons").click(function(){
   $(".content-icons").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-top-icons">
  <li>
    <a class="content-icons">primer icono</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="content-icons">segundo icono</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="content-icons">tercer icono</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cuidado con el contexto, `this` no hace referencia al elemento clickeado, debe leer más sobre [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Comment: La `arrow function` la puse como ejemplo pero ese código como tal lo he usado mucho para la pregunta que se esta haciendo y me ha funcionado con el `this`

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un snippet que funcione? Sería mucho más útil y claro :)

Comment: Mira acá, realmente lo que dive @Dev.Joel es verdad con el `arrow function` no sirve el `$(this)` https://codepen.io/dmsanchez86/pen/xBVbGz